# How to use downloaded nodeModule library locally on my Vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to use a local library downloaded using NPM (e.g. draggable-vue-directive ) and I want to use it on my project locally. 
[image]

In my Vue Project I do import it by this way when it's in my node_modules project folder:

```
import { Draggable } from 'draggable-vue-directive'
```

How can I use this library if it's presented locally ? 
I tried to do

```
import { Draggable } from '../myLibsFolder/draggable-vue-directive'
```

However I been getting this error `( ReferenceError: exports is not defined )`
It doesn't use the library correctly. I just copied the library to a local folder and tried to import it but I couldn't...

[image]

Comment: Try running `npm install` in the copied module. You're using the module in the correct way assuming your relative path goes to the correct place. Check the `package.json` file for which start file the library uses and try pointing the import there instead, e.g. a subfolder like `/lib`

Comment: try  changing it to `module.exports.Draggable = {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `import`, you can do the following.

```
const draggable = {
 // Your code here
}

export default draggable
```